# Finding a post's slug

Tags: posts, plugin-development, wp-query

I'm using `wp_query()` to get custom posts from the database. I want to list these out as links to the entries, so I'm thinking I could use the slugs. Sadly these don't seem to be included in the `wp_query` object.

Here's my code:

```
    $oWP = new wp_query(array(
        'post_type' => 'letters_of_ref'
        , 'orderby' => 'meta_value'
        , 'meta_key' => 'aaaConsultant_dateofletter'
    ));
```

So, given the post ID, how do I get the post's slug?

Alternatively, am I going down the right path to construct the link?

**Update**: just found the `get_permalink()` and `the_permalink()` functions, so I'm good for the link. Still want to find the slug though.

Comment: OK, so I just ran across an unrelated question which mention get_permalink() and the_permalink(), which are the recommended ways of getting the post's link. Still, how do I get the slug, given the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slug is already in the post object, it's `$post->post_name`.

And as you observed, yes, the way to get the post link is `get_permalink( $post->ID );`

Comment: Thanks @brasofilo. I had the whole object in front of me, but I was looking for something that said slug.

Comment: I didn't remember `post_name` as well, searched for slug in the core and found it :)

Comment: Thanks for that. Don't feel like such a n00b. Also, I have to start looking in core as well.